# Entity Framework doesn't send data to DB

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have two projects in C# that uses same DB. The difference is that one uses **EntityFramework 6** and another **System.Data.SqlClient**. They both works on PC A(Windows 10) but the problem is on PC B(Windows 7) where the version with **EntityFramework** doesn't work (it doesn't send data to database). It's hard to debug the program on PC B as it's an old laptop that can't run Visual Studio. Both programs have build-in connection string to DB. Database is hosted on Azure. Do you have any idea what can cause problems as I'm already out of ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure and what brought me more headaches than i would like to admit: On the EF machine did you call SaveChanges() after making changes to your context?

Comment: It doesn't send date to database, or doesn't send data? Do you have any logging? Can you do a database trace?

Comment: Is the connection string to the database exactly the same on PC B ? Please enable tracing and debugging.

Comment: Yes it calls SaveChanges().  It doesn't send data (sorry my mistake). The connection string is exactly the same it's the same program on PC A and PC B. It looks like EF can't connect to DB in some reason. I'll try to log more data to a file.

Comment: Azure MSSQL has a whitelist of IPs. Please ensure that both your PCs are connected to the same LAN so that both shares the same WAN IP and local firewall

Comment: @LoL I allowed IP-s from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. PC's are in the same LAN network. Anyway PC B can connect to Azure DB using System.Data.SqlClient but not while using EF